# Can I leave earlier than the duration of my German National Visa (also known as long-term visa or D visa)

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I have been invited to be a guest scientific researcher in a well known German institute. So I am applying for a German National D visa for 10 months which is the length of my contract. But I expect to get a job offer to work in a different country and may have to leave prematurely (say after 2 months).

Can there be an issue in future? For example, they might ask why I applied for such a long-term visa when I didn't have plans to stay as long.

*This post has been updated to provide more context*

Comment: I do not know the exact circumstances here, but even if you can always apply for a national visa, you will only be granted a 10 months national visa if you have a really good reason to need one (e.g,. to study) and not just 'plans to stay'. If you 'invent' such a good reason (from what you write, it does not seem to exist), that can easily be interpreted as deception and held against you in any future visa applications.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo See my updated description. I am currently between jobs and one of my ex-bosses has graciously offered me a position until I get my next job. I am worried that if I find a job early, I may have to leave prematurely. I am not sure how to disclose that at the visa interview and what kind of visa to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Plans change. You *expect* to get an offer.**

Right now your plan is to take a 10-month job, and any ideas of leaving early are "if and when." So you have no other choice than applying for a 10-month visa.

Ending that contract with all necessary notice periods and leaving earlier would be a *change* in plans, and you can make that change. Later.

Answer (score 3):

A **residence permit** is not a prison sentence that must served to the end.

It is **permit** that allows you to remain in a country for a specific period.

In Germany, a residence permit will **automatically** expire after 6 months outside the country or is to be assumed to have left permanently (left your job, deregistered and have left taking your belongings with you). (§51(1)(7) AufenthG)

The law does not forsee that any reason must be given.

Other than being a part of your traveling history, nobody will be interested.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely critical that when you apply for a visa you provide the correct and truthful information about your intentions and reasons for applying for the particular visa in question.

You cannot simply make up some reason and apply for a visa of your choice and try and get through the procedure to get it approved, as this can be considered receipt and giving false information to immigration which will most definitely impact all future visa applications.

However, if you give truthful information and receive a visa valid for x months, and then your plans change and you want/need to leave early this is not a problem as long as you follow the correct exit procedure for the visa you have.

The exit procedures can be very different depending on country and type of visa.

A simple Schengen tourist visa for example requires nothing else than simply leaving Schengen, early or not have no bearing on anything else as long as it is done in a normal situation whilst exiting for example China having a work permit and permanent residence card requires an awful lot more with proper conversion to Tourist visa etc before you exit or you will be in a world of hurt the next time you apply for any type of visa for China.